# button click not working inside the gridview using c#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a gridview that is being populated using ICallBackEventHandler as shown in below code.

```
#region ICallbackEventHandler Members
private string _Callback;
public string GetCallbackResult()
{
    return _Callback;
}

public void RaiseCallbackEvent(string eventArgument)
{
    try
    {
        DataTable dtResult = new DataTable();
        dtResult.Reset();         

        dtResult=getdata();
        gvAsync.DataSource = dtResult;
        gvAsync.DataBind();

       using (System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter())
        {            
            gvAsync.RenderControl(new HtmlTextWriter(sw));  
            _Callback =sw.ToString();
        }
     }
    catch (Exception ww1)
    {
    }
}
```

But the button inside gridview is not postbacked ,when clicked.

I have tried creating dynamic button and calling its method. Also i have registered the link button of gridview for postback. because it is in update panel.

NOTE:-

```
  gvAsync.RenderControl(new HtmlTextWriter(sw));  
              _Callback =sw.ToString();
```

The object sw converted the asp button as simple input button. May be due to this reason the control is not postbacked.
   Can anyone suggest me how can i perform the click event if the gridview is populated using ICallBackEventHandler

Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

wrap into

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    bindGridView();
}
```